# Calculating Nash equilibrium in mixed strategies for non-quadratic normal form games

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

I am wondering how to calculate the Nash equilibrium in mixed strategies if the normal form game is NOT represented by a square matrix but a non-square matrix.
I have read several books about how it works for bimatrices (that's the basic example) by solving two equations with two unknown values $p$ and $q$ (the probabilities of both players playing their "first" option).
You can also solve the problem graphically if one of the players just has two options, but this is still not a general applicable method, which I am looking for.

Can someone explain how to do it or maybe recommend good literature where the application of this case is explained?

For illustration, I just give one example of a game and it´s mixed strategies (calculated by [https://cgi.csc.liv.ac.uk/~rahul/bimatrix_solver/](https://cgi.csc.liv.ac.uk/%7Erahul/bimatrix_solver/))

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|} 
 & \text{X} & \text{Y} & \text{Z} \\ \hline
\text{A} & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
\text{B} & 2 & 1 & 0 \\ \hline
\text{C} & 1 & 2 & 1 \\ \hline
\text{D} & 0 & 1 & 2 \\ \hline
\text{E} & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

The mixed strategies in the nash eq are $\sigma_1 = (0, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 0)$ for row player and  $\sigma_2 = (0.5, 0, 0.5)$ for column player.

Answer (score 0):

For 2 by 2 games, the graphing method you are talking about works in most cases. For other cases, a general method is given in the [paper behind the bimatrix solver](http://www.maths.lse.ac.uk/Personal/stengel/ETissue/ARSvS.pdf).

Practically speaking though, you first want to eliminate the strictly dominated strategies, and then look for ways that each player can be indifferent.

So in your game, I can see that $A$ and $E$ are strictly dominated by $\frac{1}{2} B + \frac{1}{2} D$. So now we're left with a 3 by 3 game.

Now suppose P2 plays $xX + yY + (1-x-y)Z$. For P1:
$$
u_1 (B) = 2x + y, \quad u_1(C) = 1 + y, \quad u_1 (D) = 2-2x-y.
$$
We can then try to test the different cases of mixing. I'll do one case illustratively:

**P1 plays a mix between $B$ and $C$.** In order to mix between $B$ and $C$ and play $D$ with zero probability, we need $2x + y = 1 + y >2-2x-y$. This implies that $x= 1/2$ and $y>0$. So P2 must be playing $\frac{1}{2}X + yY + (\frac{1}{2} - y)Z$. Now if P1 plays $b B + (1-b)C$, then
$$u_2 (X) = 1+b, \quad u_2(Y) = 2-b, \quad u_2 (Z) = 1-b.$$
In order for P2 to be playing $X$ with $1/2$ probability, either:

- $u_2(X) = u_1(Y)$, then $b = \frac{1}{2}$. Therefore P1 plays $\frac{1}{2} B + \frac{1}{2} C$. Sicnce $u_2(Z) = \frac{1}{2}$ is less than both $u_2(X)$ and $u_2(Y)$, this forces the probability of playing $Z$ to be $0$, so P2 must be playing $\frac{1}{2} B + \frac{1}{2}C$. **This gives us the mixed equilibrium $(\frac{1}{2} B + \frac{1}{2}C, \frac{1}{2} X + \frac{1}{2} Y)$**.
- $u_2(X) = u_1(Z)$, then $b=0$. This means P1 plays $C$. However, when P1 plays C, the best response for P2 is to play $Y$. Hence we don't have any other equilibria in this case.

You then want to test the other cases: mixing between $C$ and $D$, mixing between $B$ and $D$, and mixing between $B, C$ and $D$. You can probably make use of symmetry arguments to save some time.